# How to get google play account to see default apps on fresh account?

Tags: applications, samsung-epic-4g

I've converted my old Samsung Epic 4G to a no-carrier pocket computer. I figured out how to delete the number and user info (easy, but took some effort to find out how), and then did a factory reset. With this now freshly clean phone, I added a google account (it had none at that point). I can now download apps and manage them like normal. However, my problem is that it doesn't list any of the default apps in the account (things like the calendar or the built in Internet app)--so I'm not sure how to update any of them. How do I get google play to scan for updates to these built in apps the way it did before I reset the phone?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem fixed itself. Apparently the phone needed a day before it looked for updates and propagated the My Apps list on Google Play with the pre-loaded apps.